# Is there any possible way to notify large number of users about latest update in Android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

**Problem**:

Here I want to notify about latest update to users. In present we are using API call in splash screen to show the update to users . But the problem is , in our application we have support offline usage , so users can navigate all other pagers , so we couldn't update to users.

Is there any solution to get updated data from anywhere without API call and show to users when they are in any pages?

Important:
I don't prefer API calling in every pages for this updated because it will affect app performance , in our project we have more than 40 pages and 10000 users.

We are storing updated data in web config and get that data using API call in landing screen.

Is there any solution to get updated data from anywhere without API call and show to users when they are in any pages?

Comment: I think [in-app updates](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates) are your only option for this. Of course, the device itself cannot be offline or Google Play won't detect new updates either.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing push notifications in an Android app requires several steps. You'll need to set up a push notification service (e.g., Firebase Cloud Messaging, OneSignal, or your own server), integrate it with your Android app, and send notifications from your server or a web interface. Here's a basic outline of how to implement the first option using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) in Android using Java:

Set up Firebase Project:

Go to the Firebase Console (https://console.firebase.google.com/).
Create a new Firebase project or use an existing one.
Add your Android app to the Firebase project, and follow the setup instructions to download the google-services.json configuration file.
Add Firebase to Your Android App:

In your Android Studio project, add the Firebase SDK by including the google-services Gradle plugin and the Firebase Cloud Messaging dependency in your app's build.gradle file:

Gradle :

```
// Add the following to the top-level build.gradle file
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'

// Add the following to your app-level build.gradle file
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:22.0.0'
```

Apply the Google Services Plugin:

In your app-level build.gradle file, apply the Google Services plugin at the bottom of the file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

In your app's main Application class or the onCreate method of your main activity, initialize Firebase:

```
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;

public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
    }
```

}

Implement a service that extends FirebaseMessagingService to receive and handle incoming push notifications. Override the onMessageReceived method to customize how you handle notifications when your app is in the foreground:

```
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        // Handle incoming push notifications here.
        // You can display a notification or perform custom actions.
    }
}
```

Register the Service in AndroidManifest.xml:

Add your MyFirebaseMessagingService to the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<service
    android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service
```

> 